# how to display data in dropwdowns using JSTL in spring?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp, jstl

i have PersonDTO object which has:

```
String name;
List<String> skills;//getter setter
```

when jsp loads for the first time i am getting dropdown values from @ModelAttribute like this:

```
List<PersonDTO> personInfo= personService.getInfomation(id);    
model.addAttribute("personInfo",personDTO);
```

and displaying in jsp:

```
<div>
<form:select  name="name" path="name">
<c:forEach items="${personInfo}" var="var">
<form:option value="${var.name}">"${var.name}" /></form:option>
</c:forEach>
</form:select>
<div>
<div>
<form:select  name="skills" path="skills">
<c:forEach items="${personInfo.skills}" var="skill">
<form:option value="${skill}">"${skill}" /></form:option>
</c:forEach>
</form:select>
<div>
```

so now how can i do this: if user change the name in first dropdown list then second dropdown values has to change automatically as per what ever skills that selected person has.I am using Spring 4, maven, JSTL,jQuery, javascript and spring form tag. This is all client side. Here we are not doing any ajax call with name parameter to get the skills values and displaying it in dropdown.Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You just need a javascript object that has all the names and skills, so when the name changes, the skills are already available on the client side.  Normally you would be better off doing this by serializing your list to a JSON string in the controller, but to avoid telling you to add a new dependecy like Gson to your project, you can do this by populating your javascript object in a script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var peopleSkills = {};  

    <c:forEach var="person" items="${personInfo}">
        peopleSkills['${person.name}'] = new Array();
        <c:forEach var="skill" items="${person.skills}">
            peopleSkills['${person.name}'].push('${skill}');
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>

    function updateSkills(name) {
        var skillsArray = peopleSkills[name];
        var markup = ''
        for (var i = 0; i < skillsArray.length; i++)
            markup += '<option value="' + skillsArray[i] + '">' + skillsArray[i] + '</option>';
        $('#skillsselect').html(markup);            
    }   

    $(document).ready(function(){
        updateSkills($('#nameselect').val()); // for initial option on page load

        $('#nameselect').change(function(){
            var personName = $(this).val();
            updateSkills(personName);   
        });
    });
</script>

<div>
    <form:select name="name" id="nameselect" path="name">
        <c:forEach items="${personInfo}" var="var">
            <form:option value="${var.name}">"${var.name}" /></form:option>
        </c:forEach>
    </form:select>
<div>
<div>
    <form:select name="skills" id="skillsselect" path="skills"></form:select>
<div>
```

Definitely look into creating a JSON string in your controller to avoid mixing server-side and client-side code in the script tag.  And also prepare for a situation where two different people have the same name.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me answers. but i only have one problem right now. while iterating and displaying skills,(3 names in names dropdown), first two people's skills are coming correct but some how even though third person has only one skill, dropdown is showing three. Any idea what is wrong with it? i debugged it and data are perfectly fine until i iterate over them in JSP using JSTL. first person has 3 skills, second person has 2 skills and third person has 1 skill only.

Comment: Have you looked at the html source to verify correct data in the javascript object?  Also, do any of your names have quotes in them?  If you haven't done so yet, use a javascript debugger and look for any javascript errors that are thrown when you change the name select.

Answer (score 1):

no need of `<c:foreach` to iterate all option's instead use spring `<form:options` tag like:

am considering your `PersonDTO` class has properties *id* and *name* then,

```
<form:select id="name" path="name">
  <option value="0">--select--</option>
  <form:options items="${personInfo}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id">
</form:select>
```

simillarly for skills:

```
<form:select id="skills" path="skills">
  <form:options items="${personInfo.skills}"> />
</form:select>
```

to load skills of selected person, make a AJAX get request to controller with the id of person and from controller return person skills based on person id like:

GET handler method in controller will look like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{personId}/getSkills", method=RequestMethod.GET,
        consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<Skills> getSkills(@PathVariable("personId")Integer personId){

    List<Skills> personSkills = personService.getPersonSkills(personId);
    return personSkills;
}
```

Ajax call will look like:

```
$('select#name').change(function(){
    $.getJSON('/'+$('select#name option:selected').val()+'/getSkills', function(skills) {
        $('select#skills').empty(); //first remove existing options then append new options
        $.each( skills, function( key, val ) {
            $('select#skills').append($("<option></option>")
                     .attr("value",key)
                     .text(val));
          });
    });         
 });
```

Note: to activate @ResponseBody add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` and also [Jackson mapper](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl) or any other mapper should be available on buildpath in order to work JSON serialize and deserialize.

**See Also:**

- Jquery [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)
- [how to return object from controller to ajax in spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23272814/1066779)

EDIT: As per your comment the solution will be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var peopleSkills = {};  

    <c:forEach var="person" items="${personInfo}">
        peopleSkills['${person.name}'] = new Array();
        <c:forEach var="skill" items="${person.skills}">
            peopleSkills['${person.name}'].push('${skill}');
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>

    $('select#name').change(function(){
         var skills = peopleSkills[$(this).val()];
         console.log($(this).val()+' has: '+JSON.stringify(skills));
         $('select#skills').empty();
         $.each( skills, function( key, val ) {
             $('select#skills').append($("<option></option>")
                         .attr("value",val)
                         .text(val));
         });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is only client side and i cannot  do ajax call. once all data came to the JSP that is all i cant do another ajax call name or id parameter to get skills only.

Comment: @user3388802 check answer updated, make sure select box id are same and check browser console messages too. it will work fine.