# Using AJAX call with Spring form

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I was initially trying to use Spring form tags and Validation on the Spring controller to submit form data. Since I have to update only the div in JSP page I don't think I can use this technique. So I am trying to use AJAX call. Following are the snippet of the code I have so far

Main JSP page (main.JSP)

```
<div id="header">...</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="info1">....</info">
  <div id="info2">
    <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/myForm.jsp" %>
  </div>
  <div id="info3">...</div>
  ...
</div>
<div id="footer">...</div>
```

JSP Page (myForm.jsp)

```
<form:form action="/postFormData.htm" commandName="myEntryForm">
  //All inputs using <form:input> tags
</form:form>
```

Spring MVC Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/telephone/sendMemberEntryEmail.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView doSomeWork(Model model, @Valid MyEntryForm myEntryForm, BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("myForm", "myEntryForm", myEntryForm);
    }
    return new ModelAndView("successPage");
}
```

So here I am trying to send response (both with error or succcess) to div named info2. Issue I am facing is since I am using action it is updating  whole main page with response.

Because of that I am thinking of doing AJAX call but I am not sure how I can collect form data and send to controller. I can't send each field as parameter as I have many fields and collection of related fields. I wan to send ti using MyEntryForm object.

Please suggest.

Comment: Try using form.serialize() and see. Your controller has to change as well to return data instead of MAV. Look at @ResponseBody annotation to return data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
          $("#myEntryForm").submit(function(e){
               $.ajax({
                    url: 'your form action url',
                    type: 'post',
                    data:$(this).serialize(),
                    success: function() {
                        alert('success');
                    }
                })        
           });
```

On your controller you should use @ResponseBody.

Comment: yes i figure out that part. Now next question is how can i map 'result' from controller in JSp

Comment: You need to handle the response from the controller in the ajax success and process it. Here is the post which may answer your question,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267113/how-to-return-object-from-controller-to-ajax-in-spring-mvc