# AJAX POST request to Spring MVC Controller not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am facing the error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415
>   (Unsupported Media Type)

AJAX portion of my code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/authentication/editUser',    
    type: "POST", 
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(requestObj), //Stringified JSON Object

    success: function(resposeJsonObject) {
       //
    }   
});
```

And the controller's handler method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public  EditUserResponse editUserpost(@RequestBody EditUserRequest editUserRequest) {
    System.out.println(editUserRequest);
    return new EditUserResponse();
}
```

How to resolve the error?

Comment: Try passing content type in headers.

Comment: its done in the ajax call as contentType: "application/json"

Comment: I'm saying it pass it separately in headers as `headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    }` , something like this.

Comment: Also replace this line `contentType: "application/json",` with `'dataType': 'json',`.

Comment: Do you have jackson dependencies?

Comment: try consumes = "application/json" in your controller request mapping parameters

Answer (score 1):

Manually set `Content-Type` and `Accept` in **beforeSend** handler of your AJAX function, and remove headers of your spring controller handler method to make it work like:

AJAX function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/authentication/editUser',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(requestObj), //Stringified Json Object
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }
    success: function(resposeJsonObject){}
});
```

and controller handler method like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editUser" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody EditUserResponse editUserpost(@RequestBody EditUserRequest editUserRequest){
   System.out.println(editUserRequest);
   return new EditUserResponse();
}
```

**See Also**:

- [How to return object from controller to ajax in spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23272814/1066779)

Answer (score 0):

Change your AJAX call, add headers:

```
headers: { 
    'Accept': 'application/json', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
}
```

Your overall AJAX call should look like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/authentication/editUser',    
    type: "POST", 
    headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    }
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(requestObj), //Stringified JSON Object

    success: function(resposeJsonObject) {            
        //
    }
});
```

The `Content-Type` header is used by `@RequestBody` to determine what format the data being sent.

Comment: same error persists  - POST http://localhost:8080/authentication/editUser 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Comment: Have you added  `dataType: "json",` ?

Comment: Then it should work, try removing `headers = {"Content-type=application/json"}` from `HeaderMapping` .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to remove header in controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editUser" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. i changed in controller and jquery.. hope it works

```
$.ajax({ 
        url: '/authentication/editUser',    
        type: "POST", 
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: $("#FormName").serialize()

        success: function(respose) {
           //
        }   
    });
```

And the controller's handler method:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/editUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
        headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
// removed @RequestBody 
    @ResponseBody
    public  EditUserResponse editUserpost(EditUserRequest editUserRequest) {
        System.out.println(editUserRequest);
        return new EditUserResponse();
    }
```