# SPRING WEB MVC ANNOTATIONS-Method for Partial Page Rendering

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-annotations

*Hello Friends,*

[**Need some help regarding spring web mvc annotation based:**]

How to use partial page rendering on spring web mvc annotations.

- Master Page Name:  CreateEntity.jsp
- Partial jsp page:  Account.jsp, Lead.jsp etc etc*

Now, this master page consists of drop down list where if ***Account*** is selected then partial page Account will get load into master page named *CreateEntity*. Else if ***Lead*** is Selected then Lead will get into the master page.

I have Created the Controller named CreateEntityController.java into which have written code as follows:

```
***CreateEntityController.java***
 @RequestMapping(value = { "/CreateEntity" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)  
 public ModelAndView CreateEntity(Model model) {  
 model.addAttribute("module", "Account");  
 model.addAttribute("msg", "This is the partial view page!");                                    
 return new ModelAndView("CreateEntity");
 }
```

**JSP Page Code:**
  *(CreateEntity.jsp)-**M**aster **P**age*

```
<li><c:url value="/CreateEntity" var="CreateEntity"  /> 
                            <a data-params='{"module":"CreateLeadStatus"}'
                                href="<c:out value='${CreateEntity}'/>">Create Entity</a></li>

<div>
    <%@include file="CreateLeadStatus.jsp"%>
</div>
```

**JSP Page Code 2:** *Partial Page Code: ***Account.jsp****

```
 <spring:url value="CreateEntity" var="CreateEntity" />

<form class="form-Account" action="${CreateEntity}" method="POST"  role="form" >
<div class="crmBodyWin" style="">
    <div id="" class="p30 lbox set_mw">
        <div id="secDiv_Lead_Information" class="editParentSection pL30 pR30">
            <table style="width: 100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                id="secHead_Lead_Information">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="contHeadInfo">Lead Status</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div style="width: 100%" class="secContent" border="0"
                cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" id="secContent_Lead_Information">
                <div class="contInfoTab floatL formViewCreate">
                    <div id="Leads_fldRow_COMPANY" class="textFld COMPANY tabDivCreate">
                        <div class="labelTabCreate pL5 pR newmandatory"
                            id="Crm_Leads_COMPANY_label">Status Name</div><div class="labelValCreate mL45">
                            <input
                                type="text" class="textField" style="width: 100%"
                                id="txtleadname" name="txtleadname" tabindex="5" maxlength="100"
                                data-maxlength="100" data-customfield="false"
                                data-decimal-length="2" data-label="leadname"
                                data-readonly="false" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearB"></div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
            <button class="btn btn-lg rest-btn-active btn-block" type="submit">Create Lead Status-TEST</button>
                </div>

                <div class="contInfoTab floatR formViewCreate"></div>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</form>
```

Please tell me that is there any solution for it such a manner:

*- Example:*

If{ 
(Account )-is selected then
***Account.jsp***  - partial view loads on that master page**(CreateEntity)**
}
else if (Lead)-is selected then
***Lead.jsp*** -partial view loads on that master page**(CreateEntity)**
}

module can be the common method in controller:
For example on selected choice as Account. The URL lookes something like this:

- For Account its should look something like this:

***http://localhost:8080/projectname/CreateEntity?module=Account***

- For Lead its should look something like this:

***http://localhost:8080/projectname/CreateEntity?module=Lead***

> Please kindly help me regarding this topic.
>
> Thank You!

Comment: Why you are not considering JQuery for loading of partial data? Instead of two extra jsp, just pass controller service to return dynamic data or preload the data (and show/hide using Jquery)

Comment: Hi Ankit, Thanks for your suggestion. But what about the controller method . How will it manipulate any one of the jsp page.  CreateEntity?module=Lead  . Do you have any example bro?

Comment: This will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267113/how-to-return-object-from-controller-to-ajax-in-spring-mvc#answer-23272814

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understand your question. Your goal is to include a jsp page based on your URL param(module). To do that you have to change your controller to this

```
***CreateEntityController.java***
  @RequestMapping(value = { "/CreateEntity" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)  
  public ModelAndView CreateEntity(String module,Model model) {  
      model.addAttribute("module", module);  
      model.addAttribute("msg", "This is the partial view page!");
      if(module.equals("Account"){
           //account related attributes
           // call your service or bo and send account related object
           model.addAttribute("account",yourAccountObject)
      }
      if(module.equals("Lead"){
          //lead related attributes
          // call your service or bo and send lead related object
           model.addAttribute("lead",yourLeadObject)
      }
      return new ModelAndView("CreateEntity");
  }
```

CreateEntity.jsp

```
 <%-- common code --%>
 <li>
        <a data-params='{"module":"CreateAccountStatus"}' href="<c:url value='CreateEntity?
              module=Account'/>">Create Account </a>
</li>
 <li>
        <a data-params='{"module":"CreateLeadStatus"}' href="<c:url value='CreateEntity?
              module=Lead'/>">Create Account </a>
 </li>

<div>
    <%-- Your partial condition --%>
    <c:choose>
      <c:when test="${module=='Account'}">
         <jsp:include page="Account.jsp" /> 
      </c:when>
       <c:when test="${module=='Lead'}">
         <jsp:include page="Lead.jsp" /> 
      </c:when>
    </c:choose>

</div>
```

Comment: <li class="divider"></li><li><c:url value="/CreateEntity?module=Account" var="Account" /> <a data-params='{"module":"Account"}' href="<c:out value='${Account}'/>">Account</a></li>
<li>
    <c:url value="/CreateEntity??module=Lead" var="lead_create" /> <a data-params='{"module":"Lead"}' href="<c:out value='${lead_create}'/>">Create Lead Call</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
i have modified according to you code style. Based on the query param module the value gets injected into the controller where you can check condition. You can also put @RequestParam in controller for module to eliminate confusion

Comment: Sorry. I don't.