# What is correct way to make AJAX call in Spring Boot web Thymeleaf application Getting getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am working on Spring boot based web application and using Thymeleaf on front end. I have a requirement to make a AJAX call, POST the data and on-success display data returned from the AJAX call.

below is the AJAX call to call the Controller method

```
          var myObject = new Object();
          myObject.acctTypeValue = 22;
          myObject.amtBalance = "121334";
          myObject.custNo="12121";
          myObject.userId="2345rest";
          
        $.ajax({
            url : '/testDocWeb/forwardToCallingSystem',
            type :'POST',
            data : myObject,
            dataType:'html',
            cache: false,
                 timeout: 600000,
            success : function(data) {               
                alert('Data: '+JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error : function(request,error)
            {
                alert("Error : "+JSON.stringify(request));
            }
        });
```

and below is the Spring MVC controller:-

```
    @PostMapping(path="/forwardToCallingSystem")
      public @ResponseBody DummuyResponse forwardToCallingSystem(@ModelAttribute DummyInput dummyInput,Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
         log.info("Inside forwardToCallingSystem method." );
         DummuyResponse dummyResponse = new DummuyResponse ();
         dummyResponse .setDocId("756");
         dummyResponse .setReasonCode('0');
         dummyResponse .setReturnCode(100);
         dummyResponse .setStatusCode(200);
         return dummyResponse ;
}
```

and below is the Model object which I am returning :-

```
            @Data
            @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
            public class DummyResponse implements Serializable {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -8191562770215698813L;
            private int statusCode;
            private char reasonCode;
            private int returnCode;
            private String docId;
```

}

I am not sure what is wrong but I am getting the below error on making that AJAX call:-

```
    [ERROR]~2019-06-12-10.32.54.030CDT~~~~~~ o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost] Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1013)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:388)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:348)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at net.rakugakibox.spring.boot.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackAccessTomcatValve.invoke(LogbackAccessTomcatValve.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
```

I am getting issue only on making AJAX call form Thymeleaf web page for normal Spring MVC its working fine .Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax request you are using `dataType:'html'`, But from your controller, you are returning back an Object, According to [jQuery’s Ajax-Related Methods Description](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/)

```
// The type of data we expect back
dataType : "html"
```

Update your ajax request to

```
$.ajax({
        url : '/testDocWeb/forwardToCallingSystem',
        type :'POST',
        data : myObject,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        success : function(data) {               
            alert('Data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error : function(request,error) {
            alert("Error : " + JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
```

Also, [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267113/how-to-return-an-object-from-a-spring-mvc-controller-in-response-to-ajax-request) can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer .